# error Display Datetime in Specific Format

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select mydate 
from Tble_xxx 
where CONVERT(varchar(20), mydate, 120) 
BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(20), (@startdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:m:ss:mmm', 'en-US') , 120) 
AND CONVERT(varchar(20), (@enddate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:m:ss:mmm', 'en-US'), 120)
```

When I am try to get date between to data and change the Specific Format datetime, then error occured. please Help me...

```
select mydate 
from Tble_xxx 
where CONVERT(varchar(20), mydate, 120) 
BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(20), (N'08/01/2015 12:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:m:ss:mmm', 'en-US') , 120) 
AND CONVERT(varchar(20), (N'06/04/2015 12:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:m:ss:mmm', 'en-US'), 120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME='08/01/2015 12:00:00'
DECLARE @enddate DATETIME='06/04/2015 12:00:00'

select mydate 
from Tble_xxx 
where CAST(mydate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@startdate AS DATE) AND CAST(@enddate AS DATE)
```

Comment: @johnsonANDjohnson Happy to Help :)

Comment: Surely if you need your start and end dates to be `DATE` types, you would just declare them as such, rather than as `DATETIME` and then CASTing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : let mydate be a "datetime", do not convert it ... but instead :

```
where mydate between CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-08 12:00:00', 120) and CONVERT(datetime, '2015-04-06 12:00:00', 120)
```

yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear for me why do you need to convert the date, but you can do something like this:

```
    SELECT mydate
    FROM Tble_xxx
    where mydate between CONVERT(datetime, '2015-01-08 12:00:00', 120) and CONVERT(datetime, '2015-04-06 12:00:00', 120)
```

Comment: because It is passing like a parameter that is, "@startdate" and "@enddate". in datetime datatype

Answer (score 0):

SQL server supports implicit conversion between character types (char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar) and date/time types (datetime, date, time, etc), so you do not need to use explicit `Convert` statements.

See the Data Type Conversion chart here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191530.aspx

For character/datetime conversions, it also assumes the character data will be in 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmmm' (ODBC canonical format).

> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)
>
> ODBC canonical (with milliseconds) default for time, date, datetime2, and datetimeoffset

See the "Remarks" section for date and time styles here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx

So - assuming your "myDate" field is a datetime or date type - your SQL statement can be as simple as:

```
SELECT mydate
FROM Tble_xxx 
WHERE mydate BETWEEN '2015-01-08 12:00:00' AND '2015-04-06 12:00:00'
```

If, as you mention in a comment to one of the other answers, your dates are already being passed in as datetime parameters, you can just use:

```
SELECT mydate
FROM Tble_xxx 
WHERE mydate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```